# A function similar to $.extend but adds no new attributes

Tags: jquery

I think I have seen such a jquery function, but cannot find it.

```
var x = {a:1, b:2};
var y = {a:5,     c:3};

var z = $.extend({}, x, y);   // {a: 5, b: 2, c: 3}

// want a similar jquery function which returns {a: 5, b: 2}
// that is, returns only attributes which x has (a,b), but adds no new attributes (c)
```

Comment: ...So what's your question?

Comment: is there a similar jquery function which returns `{a: 5, b: 2}`?

Comment: Use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to set enumerable as false on each properties and set true on others. Then, use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge them.

Comment: That would be a really cool in built function. I'll look into it.

Comment: @nfnneil  Yes, eg x is the default settings of a plugin,  People call the plugin with their settings y.   In the plugin you want to ignore any unknown parameters people supply.  Of course when you are the one who write the plugin you know what parameters are supported.  But if you define all known parameters as default x in the beginning (as many people do), then merge caller's parameters y and kick out attributes not defined in x, you will not accidentally be using unsupported attributes.   I think I need to write my own method for now.

Comment: I just wrote it using arrow functions because I couldn't actually find the correct function replacement.  I hope that'll do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing your own method would probably be easier here.

Go through all props of Y and override X

```
for (var yItem in Y) {
  if (X.hasOwnProperty(yItem)) { 
    X[yItem] = Y[yItem];
  }
}
```

```js
var X = {a:1, b:2};
var Y = {a:5,     c:3};
for (var yItem in Y) {
  if (X.hasOwnProperty(yItem)) { 
    X[yItem] = Y[yItem];
  }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(X));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just share another solution using `Object.assign()` and `Object.defineProperty`.

```js
var x = {a:1, b:2 };
var y = {a:5,     c:3, d:5};

Object.leftJoin = function(leftObj, rightObj) {
  var acceptKeyList = Object.keys(leftObj);
  var returnObj = {};
  
  for(var key of Object.keys(rightObj)) {
    if(acceptKeyList.indexOf(key) < 0) {
      Object.defineProperty(rightObj, key, {
        enumerable: false
      });
    }
  }
  return Object.assign(returnObj, leftObj, rightObj);
}

console.log(Object.leftJoin(x, y));
```